# MemTest86+ Errors

Tags: memtest

I have a bad stick of ram, but I'm trying to figure out the Memtest86+ reading.  At the upper right, it shows that I have a ton of errors, but only one red line is listed.

I've narrowed it down to one stick (other stick works fine in the slot and the error changes location to be 4GB higher when it's stick #2).

I'm guessing that it only lists one red line per bad cell?  Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to add your actual results. You can [upload a screenshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/217657) even if you can’t show it yet.

Comment: One single memory error is enough to tell that a RAM stick is bad.

Comment: @sudodus One of the documentations said that the first pass attempts flip adjacent bits by reading data before the ram can refresh itself.  If it only errors on the first pass, it's likely due to this (some brands are more susceptible to this type of attack).  I ran it again and more addresses showed up though.  I was just curious why only one red line.  I guess I'm more used to seeing a failed stick where it throws thousands of bad addresses (red lines) consecutively.

Comment: @pyro226 _“I'm more used to seeing a failed stick where it throws thousands of bad addresses (red lines) consecutively.”_ It depends on what fails. In the case of the address bus, you can see thousands of bad addresses failing. However, a single memory cell itself may also be failing.